# QEMU Monitor on Windows 10

Tags: qemu

I'm Ronaldo, Newbie of Stackoverflow.

I'm having a problem, On my PC it's running **Windows 10** Build 1803, Then I installed **QEMU**, but not only that, I installed the graphical version which is **QtEmu**.

Then I wanted to virtualize **CentOS 3.1**, with Disk 1, Disk 2 and Disk 3. But I don't know how to eject the disk in QtEmu, I tried it in PowerShell and I couldn't, not even in CMD, just the serial0, and the keyboard is not works, only on the PC that works. the Mouse is ok. But **QEMU** Monitor is out of QtEmu! Is there any way to install QEMU Monitor on Windows, with QtEmu?

Please help me!

Comment: Is running QEMU on Windows a requirement ?   What is your ultimate goal - to run a Centos VM ?

Comment: Yes, But I don't know eject and change the CD-ROM

Answer (score 1):

QEMU can be started with option "-monitor" so you can send commands to it there. I never used QtEmu so not sure how it starts QEMU. If you figure out how, check out https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/2012/2012-08-24/qemu-doc.html#pcsys_005fmonitor.

So basically, you can use "change" command to mount and unmount a CD drive or other storage devices. For example, "change ide1-cd0 /tmp/file.iso" to mount an image file. The device names are not fixed across different VM configurations. "info block" can tell you what name you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

sorry i just discovered QEMU, it's far now, but it can help people in the future.

I dislike QTEmu and others IHM, too much bugs currently (2022)..

With QEMU

- default mode: you can directly have an access with the window, go to view and you can switch by clicking on "compat monitor 0" . You can also detach the monitor.
- sdl: ctrl+alt 2.

Here:

- Identify your devices by "info block"

[image]

As you can see here, i ran without anything (it's just to show).

To change/add content of your cd-rom, "Change  "

- here my device is "ide1-cd0"
- Path can be your physical or virtual drive, a disk image, you can always swap according your needs.

As you can see now, i use "R:", a virtual device from a software like daemon tools (an alt).

[image]

I think it's better, before to swap, to eject from the guest... But perhaps
it depends of your OS. For the while i used it, the most of time, with win98x.